# Preventing implicit casting of int8 element inserted into int16 type ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of type int16. I want to enter an array which has a int8 type elements only. I am doing it as below:

```
original_array = np.zeros((15,), dtype=np.int16)

new_array = np.insert(original_array , 0, np.array(1).astype('int8'))
```

Output:

```
new_array = array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int16)
>>> type(new_array [0])
<class 'numpy.int16'>
```

It automatically casts the int8 to int16. Is there any way to preserve the data type of this element?

Comment: explain why you want to do this

Comment: The elements of the array will be read by another application which takes first two 8 bytes (16bytes) as one unit and read data from it, and the subsequent 8 bytes have individual data.

Comment: you are creating a new array from an original int16 array. if you'll be starting with an int8 array will work, but not the other way around as you're doing.

Comment: Then numpy array is the wrong structure for this use.

Comment: @AlessandroMariani yes, you are right. I was thinking the same way. Just wanted to check if any other way is possible. @ hpaulj It's existing implementation, thus cant change the data structure. I will convert it into int8 and modify things accordingly. Thanks for the info and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use viewcasting for this:

```
a16 = np.arange(15, dtype=np.int16)
b8 = np.array([4,19], dtype=np.int8)
ab8 = np.r_[b8, a16.view(np.int8)]
# verify
np.alltrue(a16 == ab8.view(np.int16)[1:])
```